# How to send large response with play scala

Tags: json, scala, serialization, playframework, large-data-volumes

I am using play framework 2 with Scala. From the controller I have a action method from where I need to return an object containing 100000 rows with some other data. But during JSON serialization it gets an exception at
org.json4s.native.Serialization.write(Serialization.scala:37)

it seems it can not handle that amount of data volume. Can the set the size somewhere? or what is the solution of it?

Comment: Use streaming for sending large amount of data

Comment: Can you paste the exception you're getting during json serialization? If you're getting an exception serializing the json, switching to streaming isn't going to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Chunked response can be used to send large dataset, especially the total bytes length is not known when starting sending a response. It only consumes a small amount of memory because it streams data chunk by chunk.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaStream#chunked-responses